# Is typhoeus safe to use with activerecord? resque?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency, resque, typhoeus

Is typhoeus safe to use with activerecord? resque? I've poked around in the source and googling here and there and I can't make heads or tails of it. I guess what I really want to know is, are the response callbacks run one at a time or in parallel?  Because if the callbacks are atomic or sequential or whatever then it's safe to do anything in them. I think.

Answer (score 0):

From [my answer to the github question](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/154#issuecomment-5702886):

> I've used it extensively within Resque workers. Typhoeus::Hydra
>   returns (fires #on_complete) in the order that the requests are
>   returned. Rather than doing any database work within the #on_complete
>   block, I'd suggest storing a collection of response objects and
>   performing database work after you've done any validation you might
>   need to do.